# MySQL Stackbased design for messages

Tags: mysql, database-design

Lets say you are working on a messaging system. A really basic one, you want to keep it simple so its easy to back up, easy to code, etc. Also Fast and allows for expansion over time.

What do you think about a stack based system for handling this?

For example, you have a message which is made up of the To, From, Timestamp, and a Message. All you need to do is stack those messages and when a user is signed in and wants to check their messages all you need to do is loop through the list and find all the instances where To == the currently logged in user.

Do you think this is a good way to handle this? or do you think there is a better way? Suggestions?

Comment: I changed the tags, since this is about design and has nothing to do with mysql and php in the first place.

Comment: @marc_s OT: Why have you put back the [tag:mysql]?

Comment: Sorry, wrong edits...I reverted them.

Answer (score 0):

You could design a [domain object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object) and use [SPLObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.splobjectstorage.php) to stack the messages.

I'd do the filtering (to === the currently logged in user) on SQL level, so you just load the messages the user needs to read. This reduces the load time.

Edit:

So you have a table called

### messages

- id
- senderId
- recipientId
- message
- sentDate

and a table called

### users

- id
- ...

with various other fields. This way you can join the two tables via `users.id = messages.senderId` and `users.id = messages.recipientId`. You should consider putting two indices on senderId and recipientId.

Comment: that makes sense. By Stack, i mean stack in the database. So i have 1 column that holds all the messages this way all i need to do is a SQL Request for the "TO" PARAM where its equal to the current users name or ID. Does that make sense?

Comment: Woops, sorry - I thought this was PHP related. It does indeed make sense.

Comment: so store it in an array form?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be as simple as setting up like the images depict below and the poster described above... a users table and a messages table. Consider adding a flag to denote whether the message was read or not that is updated via an onClick.

[image: Messages table]

[image: Users table]